# My code won't return anything! output is simply blank

Tags: java, boolean, stdio

I'm writing this code in java to scan numerical or alphabetical strings to see if they are consecutive. Everything seems to be working fine until I try to place a boolean in there to return true or false but nothing is happening! What am I missing? THanks! :)

Here it is:

```
public class Question1 {
  public static void main(String[]args){
    String s = "gFeD";
    isConsecutive(s);
  }
    public static boolean isConsecutive(String s){
      boolean letters;
      letters = false;
      int counter = 0;
      String newS = s.toLowerCase();
      for (int i = 0; i < newS.length() - 1; i++){
        if (newS.charAt(i) - newS.charAt(i+1) == 1){
          return true;
      } else if (newS.charAt(i) - newS.charAt(i+1) == -1) {
        return true;
      }
     }
      return letters;
    }
   }
```

Comment: `"I'm writing this code in java to scan numerical or alphabetical strings to see if they are consecutive. Everything seems to be working fine until I try to place a boolean in there to return true or false but nothing is happening! What am I missing?"` -- your code perhaps. You didn't post any code!

Comment: If you want to print anything to the console, use `System.out.println`. If you don't use it, don't expect to have anyting in your console =\

Comment: Just a note, you could simplify your `if` condition to: `if(Math.abs(newS.charAt(i) - newS.charAt(i+1)) == 1) return true;`

Answer (score 4):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < newS.length() - 1; i++){
    if (newS.charAt(i) - newS.charAt(i+1) == 1){
      return true;
  } else if (newS.charAt(i) - newS.charAt(i+1) == -1) {
    return true;
  }
```

this is not what you're after.

- You don't want to return true from *within* the for loop. Not unless you find that the order is not maintained. Else you'll return too early. On the other hand returning false is OK, again if you find that the order is in fact off.
- You don't want to check if char - otherchar == 1 or -1 as that's too restrictive. You want to look at > 0 or < 0.

Comment: +1 for a more critical look at the processing instead of just what the OP was asking about

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything with the return value.  If you want to see it on the console, do `System.out.println(isConsecutive(s));`.  That's why "nothing is happening".  It's running properly as you wrote it; it just doesn't produce any visible output.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace last line from main method with  `System.out.println(isConsecutive(s));`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing anything, try `System.out.println(isConsecutive(s));`